# java.lang.illegalargumentexception no query defined for that name [...]

Tags: java, hibernate, plsql, hql, illegalargumentexception

I have a native query in plsql like this;

```
create or replace package body DBPK_Monitoring is
  PROCEDURE monitoring_Search(cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,) is
    query       VARCHAR(30000);
    whereClause VARCHAR(10000);

  BEGIN
    whereClause := whereClause || '  and   ( cnt.contract_status!=7)';

    query := ' select itemTitle as "itemTitle", numberOfRow as "numberOfRow" ,
               orderNumber as "orderNumber",createDate as "createDate",
               priorityNumber as  "priorityNumber"  
        from buy_buy_order bbo
       inner join buy_buy_order_item bbi
          on bbi.buy_order_id = bbo.id
        left outer join core_User_Role shoUserRole
          on shoUserRole.id = bbi.buy_Expert_Id      

         ' || whereClause || ' order by ' || orderBy ||
             ') e  WHERE e.rowNO>  ' || lower_Bound || ' and e.rowNO<=' ||
             upper_Bound;
    OPEN cur FOR query
  end monitoring_Search;

end DBPK_Monitoring;
```

I use of this query in repository with hql like this :

```
 Session session = getSession();
        Query query = session.getNamedQuery("monitoring_Search").setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(MonitoringDto.class));
        int firstResultIndex = searchOption.getPageNumber() * searchOption.getPageSize();
        query.setInteger("lower_Bound", firstResultIndex);
        query.setParameter("upper_Bound", firstResultIndex + searchOption.getPageSize());
        query.setString("orderBy", searchOption.getOrder());
        query.setParameter("buyOrderNumber", buyOrderNumber);        
        List<MonitoringDto> list = query.list();
        int count = (list.size() > 0L) ? list.get(0).getNumberOfRow() : 0;
        return new QueryResult<MonitoringDto>(searchOption.getPageNumber(), count, searchOption.getPageSize(), list);
```

When I run program, I get this error:

> java.lang.illegalargumentexception no query defined for that name
>   [monitoring_Search]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you defined named query on top of entity MonitoringDto class.

Comment: no.
  Can you explain how?

Comment: just for reference https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-named-query-tutorial/

Comment: `monitoring_Search` is not a Hibernate named query. It is a stored procedure in a package. To be able to use it as a named query, you need to define it. Check the Hibernate documentation how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to define monitoring_search as a Hibernate named query , you can see the detail about this in this link : https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-named-query 
have a nice day and kiss people around you ;)

Comment: I love you eshghi. Rafti o haji haji make:D;)